# Can't set cookie for "cloudfront.net" in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

Today I found a weird thing: it seems that Chrome(46.0) set some restrictions for specific URL such as `cloudfront.net`.

It can be reproduced like this:

1. In the `/etc/hosts`, add two lines:

   127.0.0.1       cloudfront.net

   127.0.0.1       cloudfront.com
2. Start Apache or Nginx for the local server
3. Open chrome and input `cloudfront.net` in the address bar
4. Run the following statement in the console:

   document.cookie = "test=test; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2020 00:00:00 GMT;domain=cloudfront.com; path=/"
5. And then

   console.log(document.cookie)

As can be seen the `document.cookie` is empty, it is not set at all, which is weird (See the screenshot below)

[image]

However, when I repeat the steps above but change the URL from `cloudfront.net` into `cloudfront.com`, everything works well like a magic.. (See the screenshot below)

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the question in Google Group (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/Hs1838k68bw/z_h4EHVwAAAJ) . It looks that Chrome indeed set some restrictions for some sites:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/Hs1838k68bw/z_h4EHVwAAAJ

Comment: Worth mentioning directly, perhaps, this appears to trace back to the efforts of http://publicsuffix.org/ to engender more sane behavior of browsers with regard to domains that are commonly known to be under widespread use, but mixed administrative control.  Setting a cookie at the apex of `cloudfront.net` would mean that cookie would be sent to every other cf domain a user visited... a "super cookie" (not as tasty as it sounds).